# Tableau count number of times value repeated for the column, group by another two columns

Tags: group-by, count, data-visualization, tableau-api

How to count number of times "N" repeated for a particular value based on group by provider number and value in tableau? How to visualize this distribution in bar chart?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a calculated field:

```
SUM(IF [value 1] = "N" THEN 1 END)
```

Drag Provider Number to rows and the calculated field to text .

Repeat the above calculated field for more values.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help out!